# How should "Rosario + Vampire" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

How should we tag questions about the series [Rosario + Vampire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosario_%2B_Vampire)?

If we try to tag it as [rosario+vampire], the editor automatically divides it into two tags, [rosario](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosario) and [vampire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire).

I've (temporarily, unless the community agrees it should stay as is) tagged [the only existing question for the series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/why-is-tsukune-allowed-into-the-monster-school-in-rosariovampire) as [rosario-+-vampire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosario-%2b-vampire), but that looks a bit strange.

**Should we let it be as is, or retag it to something else** (like the romanization of the Japanese name)**?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's wrong with just [rosario-vampire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosario-vampire)? That shorthand is used in a lot of places where the "+" looks out of place (like in blog post URLs).

MAL has the entry a "Rosario to Vampire" but that romanization seems to be an outlier.

Comment: for this one, I agree that we should change it to [tag:rosario-vampire]. The "+" is not important enough to be distinct here, unlike how it is with [tag:blood+]

Comment: The + symbol is read as と (to, Japanese for "and"). You can even see that the と is included in the logo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rosario_%2B_vampire_vol_1_shueisha.jpg

Comment: @atlantiza But IMO, if we went for the romanization, we should also write "banpaia" instead of "vampire".

Comment: Though, I think it's important to have the official romanization in the tag wiki (with the "+", or whatever).

Comment: @JNat Those are two completely separate issues. Besides, even the image I linked actually says "vampire".

Comment: @atlantiza I think the problem with using the [tag:rosario-and-vampire] romanization is that it's not used in any official capacity. Case in point: [Funimation's pages](http://www.funimation.com/rosario-vampire/trailer/complete-season-one/7376531) has it typed with a "+" but the URL has it completely omitted ("rosario-vampire"). I think using an `-and-` is fine too, both are better than using the awkward looking "+" sign.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily trying to say we should use one specific version of the + (whether it's +, to, or and) but rather it is part of the title and should be included in some capacity since this isn't a case of a title being longer than max tag length.

Comment: @atlantiza I don't think the +/plus/to/and is essential, but if you really do feel strongly about this, maybe you should create an answer expressing this, rather than discussing it in comments. That way the community can express they're agreement with you better. :)

Answer (score 2):

This [MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77757/184716) related to the issue was listed as [status-planned](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned) for over 2 years with no real fix. User [nhahtdh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1398/nhahtdh) here (who is also a frequent MSO user) put a bounty on it to attempt to get this worked out, and it seems that the team may add more exceptions to deal with these sorts of cases.

If the tag system is changed to accommodate [rosario+vampire] we should use that as it is more correct (note that this can't be input using the current `[tag:tagname]` syntax here, but can in chat). If not, [rosario-vampire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosario-vampire) which is being used right now is an acceptable work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of several options:

1. [rosario-plus-vampire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosario-plus-vampire) (I think that's the best option).
2. Another workaround is [rosario++vampire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosario%2b%2bvampire).

We could synonym as well.

Comment: We debated this in chat, and decided to drop the + (or "plus"), as it is not important enough to keep. Plus, as Jon Lin says, most places where the + looks off, they simply use "rosario-vampire".