# How should Kiss x Sis be tagged

Tags: discussion, tags

Referring to question about [How should “Rosario + Vampire” be tagged?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-should-rosario-vampire-be-tagged) I find similar case here about Kiss x sis, now it tagged [kissxsis](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kissxsis)

Should we leave it like that or should we change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current tag is not 100% accurate to begin with.

The official translated name would be Kiss×sis instead of Kissxsis. Following google trending  [Kiss×sis](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Kiss%C3%97sis) Is a term only used in japan and would be bad for SEO.

Also I don't find this to be the same case as Rosario+vampire. As there it was mainly a issue about the fact that the + would split up the tag into 2 different tags, which is not the case here.

As for its current naming it will hit both [Kissxsis](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=kissxsis) and [kiss x sis](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=kiss%20x%20sis) searching, broadening the SEO.

For [kiss sis](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=kiss%20sis) hits both kiss x kiss and sis x kiss. Which are both pretty common typo's on the series.

There for my suggestion would be maintaining its current tag for SEO, or changing it to kiss-x-sis as this also maintains SEO.

Comment: Kiss×sis instead of Kissxsis, I almost didn't see any different if it's not because autocorret

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Difference is hard to see, thats why people mainly search for a normal X or x instead of ×  (Xx×)